# Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite

Problemas en la creación de un proyecto.

Hola comunidad, estoy tratando de crear un proyecto con spring tool suite en eclipse en spring starter project pero en las versiones de java no sale la 11 que es la que esta instalada en mi equipo. Ahora, revise en spring initializr y lo mismo. Qué sucedió con esta versión ya no esta disponible?.

Si yo creo un proyecto maven sin la ayuda de estas herramientas luego tendré problemas con mis dependencias?.

Debería utilizar la 17?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Sí, a partir de Spring Boot 3.0, solo es compatible con Java 17 o superiores.

Aquí tienes compatibilidad entre versiones de Spring Boot y java https://endoflife.date/spring-boot#java-compatibility

Saludos.